# how do i change specific rect color on a canvas in android?

Tags: java, android, colors, grid, android-canvas

ive been trying to change the color of specific rects in an array of rects when i touch the screen but it doesnt seem to be working, heres my code:

```
public Paint blue = new Paint();
RandomColorGen rc;
ArrayList<Integer> colors = RandomColorGen.ColorList(5);
Random rand = new Random();
int columns = 50;
int rows = 50;
Rect square[][] = new Rect[rows][columns];

public boolean isTouched;
public Canvas canvas;

    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++) {

            square[x][y] = new Rect();

            blue.setColor(colors.get(rand.nextInt(colors.size())));
            blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            square[x][y].set(0, 0, (canvas.getWidth() - 10) / rows,
                    ((canvas.getHeight() - 100) / columns));
            square[x][y].offsetTo(x * ((canvas.getWidth() - 10) / rows), y
                    * ((canvas.getHeight() - 100) / columns));

            canvas.drawRect(square[x][y], blue);


        }
    }
    if(isTouched){
        blue.setColor(colors.get(rand.nextInt(colors.size())));
        blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(square[1][1]);
        canvas.drawRect(square[1][1], blue);

        canvas.restore();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        isTouched = true;


        break;
    }

    return true;

}
```

the colors.get() thingy is an arraylist of colors. am i taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

How you are calling the paint function after the onTouch action performed...

OnTouch action is the first action so how do you call Paint() function??

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code, it works but there are couple of notes worth mentioning:

- Allocating objects during drawing is a very bad behavior ( specially when allocating 50*50 ) ! consider moving the allocation code to the constructor and change position of the rectangles at the `onDraw()` method if you want to achieve the same behavior you have now.
- Your usage for `onTouchEvent()` is not complete, you need to have the isTouched true as long as the user didn't raise his hand, which can be done as the following :

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      isTouched = true;


      break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
      isTouched = false;
      break;

  }
  invalidate();
  return true;
  ```

  }
- Also request a layout every time you receive a **TouchEvent** by using `invalidate()`

Comment: i tried moving it to the constructor and im getting a nullpointerexception where it says  square[x][y].set(0, 0, (canvas.getWidth() - 10) / rows,
      ((canvas.getHeight() - 100) / columns));

Comment: also, i only want to change one rects color, specifically square[1][1].